# What is the difference between X11R7.7 and X Server 1.14.4?

Tags: xorg

When I issue the command X -version in terminal window, I get the output:
X.Org X Server 1.14.4

On the X.org website, it says that latest release is X11R6.7.

I am confused why there are two version of the same thing. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X11R6.7 refers to the version number of the X.Org Window System. xorg-server 1.14.4 refers to the version number of the X server software module.

http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xorg-docs/Versions.html

Answer (score 1):

[According to the Xorg site](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xorg-docs/Versions.html#Current_Version_Numbering_Scheme), starting after X11R6.7 the numbering scheme changed to the more normative **major.minor.snapshot.**  The major number was obviously 1 and I would guess the minor number 7.

Note that these are not decimals, they are integers separated by a dots.  In other words, the minor numbers go 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, etc.  So 1.14.4 is after 1.7 (not between 1.1 and 1.2).

Answer (score 1):

The Xorg X server is a single component of the overall X Window System.  The X server is updated more frequently than the combined set of components that make up the whole system - since most distros update individual packages, there's little demand to generate large system updates just to rev the X11R7.x version of the whole system.  http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/changelog.html shows all the different components that made up the larger X Window System release for X11R7.7.

http://who-t.blogspot.com/2009/10/x11r75-released-but-what-is-it.html has a more detailed explanation from several years ago.   (As you can see since then, the overall window system has only rev'd twice, from 7.5 to 7.7, while the Xorg server updated from 1.7 to 1.15.)